# Setting List Values to Numbers in CL, and Subsequently Checking Them

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, clisp

I'm playing around in CL, making a One-Dimensional version of Battleship before I try to tackle a full Two-Dimensional version, and I've hit a hangup. To check if the boat is there, I've represented it with zeroes, and when a spot is hit, I replace it with an asterisk, so I can check the list with `numberp`. However, when I run `(new-game)`, it immediately finishes, which tells me that I'm not entering the zeroes correctly so that they are recognized as numbers. What am I doing wrong? I know it must be a rookie mistake.

```
;;;; Suez-Canal.lisp
;;;;
;;;; A simple, 1-Dimensional version of Battleship
;;;; The computer places a boat randomly, and you must sink it.

(setf *random-state* (make-random-state t))
(defparameter *boat-length* 3)
(defparameter *canal-length* 10)
(defparameter *shots-fired* 0)

(defun new-game ()
  (init-canal *canal-length*)
  (place-boat)
  (game-loop)
  (format t "It took you ~a shots to sink the boat." *shots-fired*))

(defun init-canal (len)
  (defparameter *canal* (make-list len)))

(defun place-boat ()
  (let ((pos (random-spot)))
    (setf (nth pos *canal*) 'O)
    (setf (nth (+ pos 1) *canal*) 'O)
    (setf (nth (+ pos 2) *canal*) 'O)))

(defun random-spot ()
  (let ((x (random 7)))
    x))

(defun game-loop ()
  (loop until (notany #'numberp *canal*)
       do (progn
        (prompt-for-guess)
        (check-guess (read-guess))
        (incf *shots-fired*))))

(defun prompt-for-guess ()
  (format t "~&Enter in a number between 1 and 10 to fire a shot.~&"))

(defun read-guess ()
  (parse-integer (read-line *query-io*) :junk-allowed t))

(defun check-guess (guess)
  (if (and (<= guess 9)
      (>= guess 0))
      (fire-shot guess)
      (progn
        (format t "~&Invalid selection~&")
        (check-guess (read-guess)))))

(defun fire-shot (pos)
  (if (= (nth (- pos 1) *canal*) 0)
      (progn
        (setf (nth (- pos 1) *canal*) #\*)
        (print "Hit!"))
      (print "Miss!")))
```

Comment: +1 for the name of your game. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not entering zeroes at all, but rather the letter '[O](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/O)'.

Other notes:

Do not use [DEFPARAMETER](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_defpar.htm) inside [DEFUN](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_defun.htm). Define the variable at top level, and inside the initialization function just [SETF](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_setf_.htm) it.

Do not use lists for random access. Use [arrays](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/15_.htm).

[Numerical comparison operators](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_eq_sle.htm) will signal an error when given a non-numeric value. Use [EQL](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_eql.htm) for general comparisons.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a corrected version:

```
(setf *random-state* (make-random-state t))
(defparameter *boat-length* 3)
(defparameter *canal-length* 10)
(defparameter *shots-fired* 0)

;;; you need to declare *canal* at toplevel.
(defparameter *canal* nil)

(defun new-game ()
  (init-canal *canal-length*)
  (place-boat)
  (game-loop)
  (format t "It took you ~a shots to sink the boat." *shots-fired*))

;;; just set the the variable.
(defun init-canal (length)
  (setq *canal* (make-list length)))

;;; you need to set those positions to 0 and not to O
(defun place-boat ()
  (let ((pos (random-spot)))
    (setf (nth pos       *canal*) 0)
    (setf (nth (+ pos 1) *canal*) 0)
    (setf (nth (+ pos 2) *canal*) 0)))

;;; no need for a LET
(defun random-spot ()
  (random 7))

;;; no need for progn
;;; you could also replace UNTIL NOTANY with WHILE SOME
(defun game-loop ()
  (loop until (notany #'numberp *canal*)
       do
       (prompt-for-guess)
       (check-guess (read-guess))
       (incf *shots-fired*)))

(defun prompt-for-guess ()
  (format t "~&Enter in a number between 1 and 10 to fire a shot.~&"))

(defun read-guess ()
  (parse-integer (read-line *query-io*) :junk-allowed t))

;;; <= can take more than two arguments
;;; typically this recursive version might be replaced with a LOOP
(defun check-guess (guess)
  (if (<= 0 guess 9)
      (fire-shot guess)
    (progn
      (format t "~&Invalid selection~&")
      (check-guess (read-guess)))))

;;; use EQL, = only compares numbers
(defun fire-shot (pos)
  (if (eql (nth (- pos 1) *canal*) 0)
      (progn
        (setf (nth (- pos 1) *canal*) #\*)
        (print "Hit!"))
      (print "Miss!")))
```